# Accessing attributes on literals work on all types, but not `int`; why?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, language-lawyer

I have read that everything in python is an object, and as such I started to experiment with different types and invoking *`__str__`* on them — at first I was feeling really excited, but then I got confused.

```
>>> "hello world".__str__()
'hello world'
>>> [].__str__()
'[]'
>>> 3.14.__str__()
'3.14'
>>> 3..__str__()
'3.0'
>>> 123.__str__()
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    123.__str__()
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

- Why does `something.__str__()` work for "everything" besides `int`?
- Is `123` not an *object* of type `int`?

Comment: Look at what the message says: `invalid syntax`. That is an indication that this has nothing to do with the meaning of the construct, just about how your wrote it down.

Comment: @Rusian two different questions, with answers on their own, was merged; that's why the timestamps look a bit weird.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

#### So you think you can  <strike>dance</strike>  floating-point?

`123` is just as much of an object as `3.14`, the "problem" lies within the grammar rules of the language; the parser thinks we are about to define a *float* — not an *int* with a trailing method call.

We will get the expected behavior if we wrap the number in parenthesis, as in the below.

```
>>> (123).__str__()
'123'
```

Or if we simply add some whitespace after *`123`*:

```
>>> 123 .__str__()
'123'
```

The reason it does not work for `123.__str__()` is that the *dot* following the *`123`* is interpreted as the *decimal-point* of some partially declared *floating-point*.

```
>>> 123.__str__()
  File "", line 1
    123.__str__()
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The parser tries to interpret `__str__()` as a sequence of digits, but obviously fails — and we get a *SyntaxError* basically saying that the parser stumbled upon something that it did not expect.

---

#### Elaboration

When looking at `123.__str__()` the python parser could use either *3* characters and interpret these *3* characters as an *integer*, **or** it could use *4* characters and interpret these as the **start** of a *floating-point*.

```
123.__str__()
^^^ - int
```

```
123.__str__()
^^^^- start of floating-point
```

Just as a little child would like as much cake as possible on their plate, the parser is greedy and would like to swallow as much as it can all at once — even if this isn't always the best of ideas —as such the latter ("better") alternative is chosen.

When it later realizes that `__str__()` can in no way be interpreted as the *decimals* of a *floating-point* it is already too late; *SyntaxError*.

> <sup>**Note**</sup>
>
> ```
>  123 .__str__() # works fine
> ```
>
> In the above snippet, `123`  (note the space) must be interpreted as an *integer* since no *number* can contain spaces. This means that it is semantically equivalent to `(123).__str__()`.

> <sup>**Note**</sup>
>
> ```
>  123..__str__() # works fine
> ```
>
> The above also works because a *number* can contain at most one *decimal-point*, meaning that it is equivalent to `(123.).__str__()`.

---

#### For the *language-lawyers*

This section contains the lexical definition of the relevant literals.

<sub>**[Lexical analysis - 2.4.5 Floating point literals](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/lexical_analysis.html#floating-point-literals)**</sub>

```
floatnumber   ::=  pointfloat | exponentfloat
pointfloat    ::=  [intpart] fraction | intpart "."
exponentfloat ::=  (intpart | pointfloat) exponent
intpart       ::=  digit+
fraction      ::=  "." digit+
exponent      ::=  ("e" | "E") ["+" | "-"] digit+
```

<sub>**[Lexical analysis - 2.4.4 Integer literals](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals)**</sub>

```
integer        ::=  decimalinteger | octinteger | hexinteger | bininteger
decimalinteger ::=  nonzerodigit digit* | "0"+
nonzerodigit   ::=  "1"..."9"
digit          ::=  "0"..."9"
octinteger     ::=  "0" ("o" | "O") octdigit+
hexinteger     ::=  "0" ("x" | "X") hexdigit+
bininteger     ::=  "0" ("b" | "B") bindigit+
octdigit       ::=  "0"..."7"
hexdigit       ::=  digit | "a"..."f" | "A"..."F"
bindigit       ::=  "0" | "1"
```

Answer (score 89):

You need parens:

```
(4).__str__()
```

The problem is the lexer thinks "4." is going to be a floating-point number.

Also, this works:

```
x = 4
x.__str__()
```

Comment: I much prefer the use of brackets here over a space.

Comment: The same happens with other languages, like Javascript.

Comment: @Bergi Did you read the bloody question?

Answer (score 41):

Add a space after the `4`:

```
4 .__str__()
```

Otherwise, the lexer will split this expression into the tokens `"4."`, `"__str__"`, `"("` and `")"`, i.e. the first token is interpreted as a floating point number.  The lexer always tries to build the longest possible token.

Comment: OK, but why on earth the lexer tries to build the longest possible token like this one `4.` , Why is `4.` a number in python?

Comment: @Abderrahimben: The lexers of most programming languages work by building the longest possible token.  Cases with ambiguous tokenization are  generally rare and should be avoided, and trying to automatically resolve the ambiguities would significantly complicate the lexer.  `4.` is a valid floating-point number it all programming languages I know of, including Python.

Comment: @SvenMarnach One current programming language that is an exception is C#. It makes `4` a valid literal of type `int`, and `4.0` a valid literal of type `double`, but `4.` two separate tokens. This way, `double d = 4.;` is disallowed, but the user can simply write `double d = 4.0;`. This way, `string s = 4.ToString();` *is* allowed. (You did say "all programming languages [you] know of", so you're not wrong if you don't know of C#, but it's probably a useful addition for others.)

Answer (score 6):

actually (to increase unreadability...):

```
4..hex()
```

is valid, too. it gives `'0x1.0000000000000p+2'` -- but then it's a float, of course...