# python grammar: wrong atom definition?

Tags: python, grammar

While checking python grammar at [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html), here is what it reads

```
atom_expr: ['await'] atom trailer*
atom: ('(' [yield_expr|testlist_comp] ')' |
       '[' [testlist_comp] ']' |
       '{' [dictorsetmaker] '}' |
       NAME | NUMBER | STRING+ | '...' | 'None' | 'True' | 'False')
testlist_comp: (test|star_expr) ( comp_for | (',' (test|star_expr))* [','] )
trailer: '(' [arglist] ')' | '[' subscriptlist ']' | '.' NAME
```

Then, `10.bit_length()` is a valid syntax according to that definition but not according to the python interpreter. Instead, `n=10;n.bit_length()` is valid syntax for both the specifications and the interpreter.

Where should I find the *real* definition of `atom` and `atom_expr`?

Comment: interesting. a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054229/accessing-attributes-on-literals-work-on-all-types-but-not-int-why

Comment: Also somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31037609/1639625

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to juanpa's comment and the answers in the related question, it appears that the problem comes from `10.`. The definition of NUMBER includes the dot such that `10.bit_length()` is of kind `NUMBER NAME trailer` and not `NUMBER '.' NAME trailer`.

In order to obtain an atom_expr, one must separate the dot: both `10 .bit_length()` and `(10).bit_length()` give the correct answer.