# Built-in methods does not work directly on the values of the object, but works when reference to the object is being passed

Tags: python

I was experimenting with the *built-in* methods `__lt__()`, `__gt__()` and `__eq__()`.
When I tried to do the operation directly, like
`2.__lt__(5)`, it gave output as invalid syntax instead I was expecting it to give as `True`.

when these values are being referenced through name bindings, it works fine, Like above

```
a = 2
b = 5
a.__lt__(b)
```

gives `True` as output, which is expected.

when we check the type of the object, in both scenarios it is the same as <class 'int'>

```
type(2)
<class 'int'>

type(a)
<class 'int'>
```

why does it differ when the same type of objects are being passed to the built-in methods?

Comment: You need `(2)`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is "1.real" a syntax error but "1 .real" valid in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037609/why-is-1-real-a-syntax-error-but-1-real-valid-in-python)

Comment: Yes, @user202729. that along with the explanation by Adam Smith places the concept in place to understand well.

Comment: Perhaps [python - Accessing attributes on literals work on all types, but not `int`; why? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054229/accessing-attributes-on-literals-work-on-all-types-but-not-int-why?noredirect=1&lq=1) is a better question.

Comment: "directly on the values of the object". That isn't what `1` is. `1` is a literal, which *evaluates* to an object. The same as a simple `a` expression. It is no more "direct" than using `a`. The type isn't relevant, you are getting a *syntax error*.

Answer (score 2):

`2.__something__` is ambiguous, because `2.3` is valid syntax for a float literal. Indeed since you can use single underscores almost anywhere in numeric literals (e.g. `1_000_000 == 1000000` and `3.141_59 == 3.14159`), it's difficult to create consistency without forcing some sort of special syntax. You can remove the ambiguity by parenthesizing the expression:

```py
(2).__lt__(5)
```

then it behaves equivalently to other objects.

```py
[2, 3, 4].pop()
# or
"this, that, the other".split(',')
# etc...
```

Comment: Well explained! Thanks